# Cut the height of a histogram in python

Tags: python, histogram

I need to plot a histogram in python, but I want to cut all bins with a height greater than a certain value (for example if the limit is 500 and a bin has 550 element, I want to show it on the histogram only up to 500, without removing the actual values stored in the bin). How can I do this.

Comment: …using what library? Matplotlib? Gnuplot? Numpy? Something else?

Comment: I can use any library, I don't know which one can do this so I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should certainly use `numpy.clip` on plotted values

Comment: How can I use it for a histogram? I mean I guess I have to use for height of the bins, but can I do this while the histogram is created or I have to modify it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

You could cut store the clipped values in a separate list.

```
vals = [100, 250, 50, 550, 6000]

cut_vals = [min(val, 500) for val in vals]
print cut_vals

#Output
[100, 250, 50, 500, 500]
```